# Imagemin svgo delete path

Tags: javascript, svg, gulp, gulp-imagemin, imagemin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="icons" transform="translate(-368.000000, -426.000000)">
            <g id="attention-blue" transform="translate(368.000000, 426.000000)">
                <circle id="Oval-13" fill="#34C6D9" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"></circle>
                <path d="M10,10.8 L10,5.6" id="Line" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                <path d="M10,14.8 L10,14.8" id="Line2" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I have SVG icon with two "path" tags. After building with imagemin.svgo imagemin remove one of this "path" and my icon looks very bad. How can I fix this?

```
gimagemin.svgo({
    plugins: [
      {minifyStyles: false},
      { removeViewBox: false },
      { removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false },
      { cleanupIDs: false }
        ]
  })
```

This is my options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, SVGO doesn't remove the second path, it merges it into the first one (it's done by “mergePath” plugin enabled by default). **But**, since the second path has zero length, SVGO removes the “lineto” (“L10,14.8”) command (“convertPathData” plugin does that), so it reduces to just useless “moveto” (`M10 14.8`) command.

I'd recommend not to draw images in a such style. You may use another `<circle>`, or draw a circle in a path with [arc curves](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands).

Of course, you can disable “convertPathData” plugin for this particular image, but I don't recommend it as a general solution, since it's one of the basic optimization plugins.